# Terminating app due to uncaught exception while running app

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am making a game in which if I press a button the player (circuloPrincipal) changes to the color to a color determinate by the button.
When I run my game sometimes crashes with the error below. I havent find the error, because I cont know how to interpretate

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:  name:'button4' texture:[ 'circuloBoton' (100 x 100)] position:{407, 39} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{60, 60} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00'

```
    circuloPrincipal.size = CGSize(width: 225, height: 225)
    circuloPrincipal.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height / 2)
    circuloPrincipal.color = colorAzul
    circuloPrincipal.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
    circuloPrincipal.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: circuloPrincipal.size.height / 2)
    circuloPrincipal.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategory.circuloPrincipal
    circuloPrincipal.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCategory.enemigo
    circuloPrincipal.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategory.enemigo
    circuloPrincipal.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    circuloPrincipal.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    circuloPrincipal.name = "circuloPrincipal"
    circuloPrincipal.zPosition = 5.0
    circuloBlanco.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
    circuloBlanco.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2 - 105 ,  y: frame.height / 2 - 345)
    circuloBlanco.color = colorBlanco
    circuloBlanco.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
    circuloBlanco.zPosition = 4.0

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    /* Called when a touch begins */

    if gameStarted == false {

        circuloVerde.removeFromParent()
        circuloMorado.removeFromParent()
        circuloRojo.removeFromParent()
        circuloBlanco.removeFromParent()


        circuloPrincipal.color = colorAzul

        enemigoTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.7, target: self, selector: Selector("enemigos"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        gameStarted = true
        circuloPrincipal.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.44, duration: 0.4))
        score = 0
        scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
        hits = 0
        highscoreLabel.runAction(SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.5))    
    }

    circuloVerde.name = "button"

    let touch = touches.first
    let positionInScene = touch!.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)

    if let name = touchedNode.name {
        if name == "button" {     
            circuloPrincipal.color = colorVerde
        }  
    }

    circuloAmarillo.name = "button2"

    let touch2 = touches.first
    let positionInScene2 = touch2!.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode2 = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene2)

    if let name = touchedNode2.name {
        if name == "button2" { 
            circuloPrincipal.color = colorAmarillo    
        }
    }

    circuloAzul.name = "button3"

    let touch3 = touches.first
    let positionInScene3 = touch3!.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode3 = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene3)

    if let name = touchedNode3.name {
        if name == "button3" {
            //do my stuff
            circuloPrincipal.color = colorAzul  
        }
    }

    circuloBlanco.name = "button4"

    let touch4 = touches.first
    let positionInScene4 = touch4!.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode4 = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene4)

    if let name = touchedNode4.name {
        if name == "button4" {
            circuloPrincipal.color = colorBlanco
        }
    }

    circuloRojo.name = "button5"

    let touch5 = touches.first
    let positionInScene5 = touch5!.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode5 = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene5)

    if let name = touchedNode5.name {   
        if name == "button5" {
            circuloPrincipal.color = colorRojo  
        }
    }

    circuloMorado.name = "button6"

    let touch6 = touches.first
    let positionInScene6 = touch6!.locationInNode(self)

    let touchedNode6 = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene6)

    if let name = touchedNode6.name {
        if name == "button6" {
            circuloPrincipal.color = colorMorado 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no offence, but your code was a mess. You should consider cleaning up all the extra white space and format it before asking people to read it.

Comment: I'm running what I can of your code, and it works fine. But there is huge chunks of the code missing (I just commented out lines that are affected). Can you post the enemigos function so I can see what is happening in there?

Comment: sure, and Ron it happen sometimes

Comment: that's why I think that the problem lies in the enemigos function because with that call commented out I can hammer the buttons and change color forever with no error

Comment: I added to my question Ron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're trying to add a node but it already has a parent.  its right there in the error message.

you can check to see if it already has a parent like this

```
let childNode = SKNode()
let parentNode = SKNode()

if childNode.parent == nil {
    parentNode.addChild(childNode)
}
```

Comment: This is a fine fail safe, but it doesn't address the issue of why he is trying to add the object twice.

Comment: Yeah he doesn't need to do that but if he doesn't want to address it he can just use the fall safe

Comment: Thanks a lot Ron for your time